# ASP.NET MVC Insert query duplicate data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am sending my oracle database an insert query through MVC ACTION somehow, the insert method is being called twice and records the same data twice...

Also, using the same structure running a select query returns the same result twice.

What am I missing?

View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click", "reg",
 new AjaxOptions
{       
    HttpMethod = "POST"
})
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult reg()
    {
        KullaniciYetkiDAL.Add();

        return View();

    }
```

DAL:

```
 public static void Add()
    {
        string Query = "insert into USER (id,PROGRAM_ID) values ('200',1)";
        Database.EXECUTE(Query, null);
        Database.CloseConnection();
    }
```

DBAcsess:

```
 public static int EXECUTE(String Query, List<OracleParameter> Params)
    {
        Command = new OracleCommand(Query, GetConnection());
        if (Params != null)
        {
            foreach (OracleParameter p in Params)
            {
                Command.Parameters.Add(p);
            }

        }
        return Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I cant understand why its request twice,but I think you can check your view , try to change method that use the native **Jquery** to request the **Action**

Answer (score 0):

You should change your link to Html.ActionLink because Ajax is storing the request instead of Ajax you have to use Html.ActionLink :

```
@Html.ActionLink(TestAction.Title,
    new { controller = "TestController", action = "TestAction",
          id = TestAction.ID })
```

Comment: i think my problem about project architecture, not how i send to request.

Comment: But still you need to check ajax call as well.

Comment: Yea u got right there i change request this way and worked@using (Html.BeginForm("YetkiVer", "KullaniciYetki", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="submit" value="sumit" />
}. but why?

Comment: yah ajax.html form storing the request while running the page that's why many request get stored in there session and unnecessary calling the same action multiple times. So best way is use @Html.BeginForm

Comment: Thanks sir. This answer fixed my problem.